# Install Win7 theme on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows-7, themes

I'm totally new to Ubuntu. I've installed version 16.04 and I'm having trouble finding my way around. I've tried just about all possible ways to make Ubuntu look like windows 7. Every way I tried was missing something, Is there a way to make version 16.04 be like win7?

Comment: Just curious, Why do you want Ubuntu to look like windows 7 ?? Do you make Windows look like ubuntu ? no offense :-)

Comment: I think the issue he is having is the crazy unity stuff in basic Ubuntu. He would be better off with Xubuntu which has a more "windows" like interface

Comment: Severus Tux . I don't want it to look like windows, I want to deal with it the way I was used to in windows. I  61 years old and I don't have the patience to deal with the crazy unity stuff in Basic Ubuntu. Just like John Orion said.. Thank you Joihn Ortion. I'm still open for suggestions and willing to try.

Comment: @AbedaSamir Just a suggestion: If you expect things to behave like the old ones, you'll never take advantage of what's actually good.

Comment: NO I don't expect that, I just expect development to easier for the user. I am ready to read, but  at the same time I simply expect easier and closer to the user. especially that I'm neither an IT Expert nor  a programmer. Maybe I expected to much, but I really think that a huge,   strong  operating system developer should consider this point specifically for home user edition. That is all with all respect and appreciation to all efforts.

Comment: Questions like "why do you want it" seem a bit unwarranted. I want it too, for my own personal reasons.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/55985/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7/) looks pretty convincing.

Answer (score 2):

The closest I have managed to get for 16.04 is a Windows 10 theme with the usual Window icons by doing the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
sudo apt update && sudo apt install windos-10-themes && sudo apt install win-icons
```

Comment: II;m planning to try 15.10 mate. then maybe Xubuntu. if  I don't face wifi connection. They all except for 15.10 do not ignite the wifi. with no use of additional drivers.